# Go web framework (similar to Rails)

Tags: framework, go

I come from Ruby and Rails framework environment, which offers me a lot of useful stuff.

However I'd like to move towards Go now. So far Rails provide a bunch of useful features:

- JSON rendering
- Assets pipeline and sprockets compilation
- Managing headers, cookies
- Easy deployment
- ActiveRecord as a ORM

I'm looking for something similar with Go. I found [Revel](http://revel.github.io) framework, which is quite comprehensive, however it is missing some features (like CoffeeScript and Sass compilation, assets pipeline - CSS and JS concatenation, ORMs).

Are there any Rails similar Go frameworks? What can you recommend to start with?

I know that I can start and learn just `fmt` and `http` packages, but this is the same as learning `rack`, which may be helpful, but totally unnecessary (I learned rack after a half a year with RoR).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come from a Python and web2py background (I **love** web2py!). So I was looking for something similar in the Go community. I, too, looked at Revel, but it seemed to be lacking in maturity (it's not even at Version 1.0 yet), and I hate that it doesn't have a built-in ORM.

I've adopted Beego. It's not as good (ie, easy and productive) as web2py, but for the time being it's about as good as it's going to get.

Beego has all the major pieces of a full-stack framework in place. There may be a few gaps here and there, but overall I think it's a fairly complete system. In fact, I am such a big believer in full-stack frameworks that I wrote an [advanced tutorial for Beego](https://medium.com/@richardeng/a-word-from-the-beegoist-d562ff8589d7).